# How to remove the window icon in PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5, window, icons

How can I remove this icon from the window in PyQt5?
[image: icon]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide detailed information about your problem and what you did try before posting. Please, check [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a question for more details as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this easily

```
self.setWindowIcon(QIcon("c:/1.png"))
```

and copy transparent icon to c: drive as '1.png'